# Jboss Spring Boot Jpa custom querie with params not working

Tags: html, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have an application with custom queries that work perfect on Tomcat server, but not working in `jboss` server.

The customs query is:

```
@Query("SELECT r  "
            + "FROM RevisionIndividual r "
            + "WHERE (:name is null or LOWER(r.paciente.name) LIKE LOWER(:name) "
            + "or LOWER(r.paciente.surname) LIKE LOWER(:name) "
            + "or LOWER(r.paciente.surname2) LIKE LOWER(:name)) "
            + "and (:idPaciente is null or r.paciente.simiveId = :idPaciente) "
            + "and (:origen is null or r.tipoOrigen = :origen) "
            + "and (cast(:fecha as date) is null or DATE(r.fechaNotificacion) = cast(:fecha as date)) "
            + "and (:tipo is null or r.tipoRevisionIndividual = :tipo) "
            + "and (:estado is null or r.estadoRevisionIndividual = :estado)")
    public Page<RevisionIndividual> findAllFiltered(@Param("name")String name, @Param("idPaciente")Long idPaciente, @Param("origen")TipoOrigen origen, @Param("fecha") @Temporal Date fecha , @Param("tipo")TipoRevisionIndividual tipo, @Param("estado")EstadoRevisionIndividual estado, Pageable pageable);
```

At the log in the Tomcat server i see the custom querie runs ok:

```
2020-09-27 22:39:08,331 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [http-nio-8089-exec-8] select tipoorigen0_.id as id1_15_, tipoorigen0_.descripcion as descripc2_15_, tipoorigen0_.end_point_hup_client as end_poin3_15_, tipoorigen0_.nombre as nombre4_15_ from tipo_origen tipoorigen0_
2020-09-27 22:39:08,441 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [http-nio-8089-exec-8] select tiporevisi0_.id as id1_16_, tiporevisi0_.descripcion as descripc2_16_, tiporevisi0_.nombre as nombre3_16_ from tipo_revision_individual tiporevisi0_
2020-09-27 22:39:08,549 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [http-nio-8089-exec-8] select estadorevi0_.id as id1_2_, estadorevi0_.descripcion as descripc2_2_, estadorevi0_.nombre as nombre3_2_ from estado_revision_individual estadorevi0_
2020-09-27 22:39:08,635 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [http-nio-8089-exec-8] select revisionin0_.id as id1_14_, revisionin0_.date_created as date_cre2_14_, revisionin0_.id_estado_revision_individual as id_estad6_14_, revisionin0_.fecha_notificacion as fecha_no3_14_, revisionin0_.id_registro_origen as id_regis4_14_, revisionin0_.simiveid_paciente as simiveid7_14_, revisionin0_.simive_time_stamp as simive_t5_14_, revisionin0_.id_tipo_edo as id_tipo_8_14_, revisionin0_.id_tipo_origen as id_tipo_9_14_, revisionin0_.id_tipo_revision_individual as id_tipo10_14_ from revision_individual revisionin0_ cross join pacientes pacientes1_ where revisionin0_.simiveid_paciente=pacientes1_.simive_id and (? is null or lower(pacientes1_.name) like lower(?) or lower(pacientes1_.surname) like lower(?) or lower(pacientes1_.surname2) like lower(?)) and (? is null or revisionin0_.simiveid_paciente=?) and (? is null or revisionin0_.id_tipo_origen=?) and (cast(? as date) is null or DATE(revisionin0_.fecha_notificacion)=cast(? as date)) and (? is null or revisionin0_.id_tipo_revision_individual=?) and (? is null or revisionin0_.id_estado_revision_individual=?) limit ?
2020-09-27 22:39:08,636 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [%el%]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,636 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [%el%]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,637 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [%el%]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,637 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [%el%]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,637 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,638 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,638 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,638 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [8] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,639 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [9] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,639 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [10] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,639 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [11] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,640 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [12] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,640 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [13] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-09-27 22:39:08,640 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [http-nio-8089-exec-8] binding parameter [14] as [BIGINT] - [null]
```

But at the log in the Jboss server it seems there is a problem with the binding:

```
2020-09-28 12:04:42,825 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [default task-5] select tipoorigen0_.id as id1_15_, tipoorigen0_.descripcion as descripc2_15_, tipoorigen0_.end_point_hup_client as end_poin3_15_, tipoorigen0_.nombre as nombre4_15_ from tipo_origen tipoorigen0_
2020-09-28 12:04:42,831 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [default task-5] select estadorevi0_.id as id1_2_, estadorevi0_.descripcion as descripc2_2_, estadorevi0_.nombre as nombre3_2_ from estado_revision_individual estadorevi0_
2020-09-28 12:04:42,835 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [default task-5] select tiporevisi0_.id as id1_16_, tiporevisi0_.descripcion as descripc2_16_, tiporevisi0_.nombre as nombre3_16_ from tipo_revision_individual tiporevisi0_
2020-09-28 12:04:42,842 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger [default task-5] select tiporevisi0_.id as id1_16_, tiporevisi0_.descripcion as descripc2_16_, tiporevisi0_.nombre as nombre3_16_ from tipo_revision_individual tiporevisi0_ where tiporevisi0_.nombre=?
2020-09-28 12:04:42,843 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder [default task-5] binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - []
2020-09-28 12:04:42,894 ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine [default task-5] [THYMELEAF][default task-5] Exception processing template "/fuenteDatos/revisionIndividual": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//fuenteDatos/revisionIndividual.html]")
```

The query returns null and then I get a failed in the HTML code because no page info is available.

Any thoughts about why this query is not working at `Jboss` server? The rest of the queries works fine in the `jboss` server.

Comment: Why you think that this error related to the mentioned sql query?

Comment: The aplication run fine until i use the filters that call that sql query

Comment: looks to me that your parameter is not correctly parsed, hence the parsing error, the error occurs when the first paramter is supposed to be bound, which is the name. I don't see how the query can be at fault for the error. Maybe investigate further on your thymeleaf binding.